# Nouns as adjectives

Tags: adjectives, nouns

"Personality-career match" I found this term on careerkey.org.

So, this compound noun tells you about a match between your personality and major. So, I surmised that the rule here is "**noun-noun match."**

In this sense, can I say

**1. Partner-personality match.**

**2. Computer-preference match.**

**3. Muscle-building-program** **match.**

Comment: I suppose you could.  But the example "personality-career match" is an odd usage of noun-noun as adjective.  I would have rendered it as "personality/career match".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the ones you have listed can be said.